# Typescript return an array with manipulation on the objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

My question seems very simple, but I didn't find a simple way to do it.

In Typescript, I want to return an array with manipulation on each object inside.

For example:

```
foo = [{code: 1, desc:"a"},
       {code: 2, desc:"b"},
       {code: 3, desc:"c"}];

get Foo() {
   return this.foo.forEach((item) => {
       return {code:item.code + 1, desc: item.desc};
   });
}
```

This getter returns undefined.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You're looking for [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything, or `undefined`.

You probably want [the `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead.